# Spring MVC 3 formatting BigDecimal

Tags: java, spring-mvc, formatting, bigdecimal

In my application, most `BigDecimal` numbers in forms are formatted to 2 decimal values. So I have my own `BigDecimal to String converter` in `ConversionService` (to override locale to use decimal comma instead of dot). But on specific places, i need to change that format to for example 4 decimal values. What is the best way to achieve that? I tried using `@NumberFormat` annotation, but I also need to use decimal comma.

Also, how does `ConversionService` and `@NumberFormat` interfere with each other in Spring MVC 3? Specifically, in `<spring:form>` tags? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your 2dp values are currency values then you might like to try wrapping them in a custom "Money" type. You could then write a formatter that displayes to 2dp but in the future it would also give you the flexibillity to introduce a currency value and possibly include that in the output. E.G. £2.99 or 2,99€.

I first read about this pattern in Martin Fowlers patterns of enterprise architecture.
http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/money.html

I know it doesn't answer your specific question but I thought it might be a useful consideration that could lead you to the right answer. Hope it helps.